# Line continuation in rdoc

Tags: rdoc, yard

I have inherited a bunch of Ruby code with rdoc comments, but many of the options and attributes are multi-line, such as:

```
# +param+:: Here is a parameter with a really long description
#  that won't fit in one line
```

The end result is really hard to read docs using rdoc, sdoc, or yard. Each displays the second line in a different way. Am I missing something? Is there some way to retain line wraps, but make the generated documentation come out correct?

Comment: it seems not possible

Answer (score 3):

In YARD it's possible to continue the line by simply **adding another comment line without any special annotation, just indent** of at least two characters.
You can find it documented here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md

For example this code below:

```
# class description
class Test
  # @param [String] one this parameter has an astonishingly
  #  long description
  def method(one)
    nil
  end
end
```

renders as

[image: YARD render]